# Datepicker not show when I check textbox(use asp.net web form)

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I tried to use datepicker from jQUERY ui, but it didnt show calendar when I click textbox.
I tried my best to try different ways but it still not work.
I used this code: https://jqueryui.com/datepicker

And this is my aspx code:(I had used master page)

```
    <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#<%=datepicker.ClientID %>').datepicker();
            });
    </script>
    </asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
<asp:TextBox ID="datepicker" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</asp:Content>
```

Can anyone help me? thank you all firstly.

Comment: If i paste this code to a page it works fine. Check your browser console for errors that could prevent the datepicker from working.

Comment: Thank you, I thought it might be something wrong from my master page

Answer (score 0):

Your code worked fine for me in the form without a master paged , there is a conflict in your master page and your aspx page.

Comment: Thank you！I will try what's wrong with my master page